# Matrix of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Given: 
$$ f_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
3 \\         
5 
\end{pmatrix}, 
f_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\         
2 
\end{pmatrix}, 
f_3=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\         
0 
\end{pmatrix}, 
\\ g_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\         
1 
\end{pmatrix}, 
 g_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\         
-1 
\end{pmatrix}, 
g_3=\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
1 \\         
2 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$ $$A(f_1)=g_1, A(f_2)=g_2, A(f_3)=g_3$$
What is the matrix A  of that linear operator in basis ${e_1,e_2,e_3}.$
I know that $i$ column of matrix $A$ is $A(e_i)$. How can I understand what's happening with basis vectors through given transformaions? I have no clue. Please help.

Comment: Try to write $e_1, e_2$ and $e_3$ in the basis $\{ f_1,f_2,f_3 \}$. After that, use the linearity of $A$ to find $A(e_i)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F = [f_1, f_2, f_3], G = [g_1,g_2,g_3]$

$AF = G\\
A = AFF^{-1} = GF^{-1} $